# Convert GregorianCalendar to Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a javascript variable initialized as below

```
var updateDate = Model.updateDate;
```

and `Model.updateDate` is having the value

`java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1564159232000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=30,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=26,DAY_OF_YEAR=207,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=40,SECOND=32,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]`

Is there any way that we can convert `Model.updateDate` to into Date format so that it would look like this

```
var updateDate = 2020-01-03;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part do you wish to convert to a date, is it "time=1564159232000"? What have you tried? Where are you having issues?

Comment: @RobG I want to get the `YEAR=2019` of the GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Typically you'd split the string on "," (comma), then iterate over the sub–strings and split on the "=" (equals) to get the name/value pairs. Then do whatever you want with the result.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the solutions you are looking for, I use angular

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>date1 = {{ today | date: "dd/MM/y" }}</p>
<p>date2 = {{ today | date: "y" }}</p>
<p>date3 = {{ today | date: "dd/MM" }}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    var str = "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1564159232000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id='UTC',offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=30,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=26,DAY_OF_YEAR=207,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=40,SECOND=32,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]";
  $scope.today = str.substring(33, 46);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

result date1 = 26/07/2019

date2 = 2019

date3 = 26/07
```

Comment: Could you please write in English.